# PHP post of td content inside a for

Tags: php, forms

I just need to send a line of a table in my PHP page after click on button.
This is my code :

```
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $requete = Connexion::query("SELECT id
                                 FROM session
                                 WHERE login='$login'");
    $requete = $requete[0][0];
    $application = Connexion::query("SELECT titre,cleAk,cleAs,cleCk 
                                     FROM cles
                                     WHERE sessionId='$requete'");


    echo "<form class='login-form' method='POST'><table class='table'><th>Titre</th><th>Cle ak</th><th>Cle as</th><th>Cle ck</th><tr>";

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($application);$i++)
    {   
        for($j=0;$j<4;$j++)
        {
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='titre' value='".$application[$i][$j]."'>".$application[$i][$j]."</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td></tr></form>";
    }
```

And this var_dump($_POST['titre']); return the last cell of the last line.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Send a line where?

Comment: Send a line with a POST

Comment: You mean post a form?

Comment: Yes, POST with my form

Comment: Change name='titre' to name[]='titre'

Comment: This didn't work to "Change name='titre' to name[]='titre'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was briefly [mentioned in the comments of a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/62843449), if you only want to submit the contents of one line, then you will need a separate `<form>` on every line (table row). You were trying this with a closing `</form>` inside the loop, but you opened it outside the loop resulting in invalid HTML with lots of closing `</form>` tags but only one opening `<form>` tag.

Another problem with your form inputs is that they were all named the same after the first column `name='titre'` but you had specified each column separately in the table header. To fix this, others offered an imprecise option by creating an array `name='titre[]'`, but I think it's better to dynamically name the inputs to match the column key.

I don't know what database API you're using, but it appears to only produce a numeric multidimensional array without associative keys. There's probably a class method to get the column names, or you can manually assign it based on your SQL query as I have done with the array `$cols`

```
<?php

// debugging to show you everything posted
print_r($_POST);

// generate some random data for example
$application[0][0] = "first titre";
$application[0][1] = "first cleAk";
$application[0][2] = "first cleAs";
$application[0][3] = "first cleCk";

$application[1][0] = "second titre";
$application[1][1] = "second cleAk";
$application[1][2] = "second cleAs";
$application[1][3] = "second cleCk";

$application[2][0] = "third titre";
$application[2][1] = "third cleAk";
$application[2][2] = "third cleAs";
$application[2][3] = "third cleCk";

// get the columns for input names
$cols = array('titre','cleAk','cleAs','cleCk');

// semantically complete HTML table
echo "
<table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Titre</th><th>Cle ak</th><th>Cle as</th><th>Cle ck</th><th>Submit</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
";

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($application);$i++)
{
    echo "
    <tr>
      <form class='login-form' method='POST'>";

    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($cols);$j++)
    {
        echo "
        <td><input type='hidden' name='".$cols[$j]."' value='".$application[$i][$j]."'>".$application[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }

    echo "
        <td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td>
      </form>
    </tr>\n";
}

echo "
  </tbody>
</table>
";
```

Results in this rendered output when I click on the first row's submit button. **Note** that you can't post data in the snippet below, this is purely for static HTML demonstration purposes.

```html
Array
(
    [titre] => first titre
    [cleAk] => first cleAk
    [cleAs] => first cleAs
    [cleCk] => first cleCk
    [api] => 
)

<table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Titre</th><th>Cle ak</th><th>Cle as</th><th>Cle ck</th><th>Submit</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <form class='login-form' method='POST'>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='titre' value='first titre'>first titre</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleAk' value='first cleAk'>first cleAk</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleAs' value='first cleAs'>first cleAs</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleCk' value='first cleCk'>first cleCk</td>
        <td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td>
      </form>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <form class='login-form' method='POST'>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='titre' value='second titre'>second titre</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleAk' value='second cleAk'>second cleAk</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleAs' value='second cleAs'>second cleAs</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleCk' value='second cleCk'>second cleCk</td>
        <td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td>
      </form>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <form class='login-form' method='POST'>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='titre' value='third titre'>third titre</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleAk' value='third cleAk'>third cleAk</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleAs' value='third cleAs'>third cleAs</td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='cleCk' value='third cleCk'>third cleCk</td>
        <td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td>
      </form>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array to handle the multiple elements with the inputs. In Your code it should be look like this:

```
 for($j=0;$j<4;$j++)
    {
        echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='titre[$j]' value='".$application[$i][$j]."'>".$application[$i][$j]."</td>";
        echo "<td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td></tr></form>";
    }
```

The modification is name='titre[]'. Hope this will help you

Comment: It return all lines in table I just want the line of the button

Comment: Can't understood what you are saying. Please clarify once again

Comment: Your solution : titre[] return all content(cells) of the table. And, i try to return the line where the button is clicked. (one button on each line)

Comment: @AdrienG If you just want one line to be submitted, you need to put a separate form in each row of the table. Or use AJAX to get the data from the row of the button and submit it.

Comment: echo "<td><button type='submit' name='api'>Submit</button></td></tr></form>"; write this line between the for loop

Comment: It return the last line of the table @asif

Comment: please check out the recent update of my answer and if it works please up vote the answer